# how to aggregate and sum at the same time in df?

Tags: r, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a selection of my data frame that looks like this:

```
Año                             Bien.jurídico.afectado         totalincidencia
1   2015                   La vida y la Integridad corporal              88
2   2015                   La vida y la Integridad corporal              18
3   2016                   Afectaciones         Patrimonio               36
4   2017                   La vida y la Integridad corporal               0
5   2017                   Otros delitos                                  0
```

What I what is to aggregate the column "Bien.jurídico.afectado" by each category and at the same time sum the column "totalincidencia" to get something like this:

```
2015     La vida y la integridad corpotal 106
```

I have tried different methods without success tho, because either it affects the date when I aggregate or it doesn´t sum the last column.

Any tip will be highly appreciated

Comment: Could you fix formatting? This will help readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `dplyr`?

```
library(dplyr)

your_dataframe %>%
   group_by(Año, Bien.jurídico.afectado) %>%
   summarise(total = sum(totalincidencia))
```